# dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() Does not work

Tags: java, android, database, android-contentprovider, sqliteopenhelper

I have a custom ContentProvider, with a custom member SQLiteDatabaseHelper
While trying to insert to my database, inside my insert, I instantiate my DatabaseHelper, and then I try to call getWritableDatabase() on that instance to get an SQLiteDatabase object, but I get a force close on the getWritableDatabase() call.

My activity:

```
public class UserForm extends Activity {
    public void onSubmitClick(View v){
        userDatabase db = new userDatabase();
        db.insert(userDatabase.CONTENT_URI, null);
    ...}
...}
```

My Helper code:

```
public static final class MainDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public MainDatabaseHelper(Context context) {            
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_MAIN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
    }
}
```

My insert:

```
public class userDatabase extends ContentProvider {
     public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
              MainDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MainDatabaseHelper(getContext());
              SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ...}
...}
```

I get a force close on this last line.

I know the dbHelper isn't null.
I know the dbHelper constructor ran.
BUT the dbHelper onCreate has never run.

My guess is the issue is the helper is instantiated but never created, what could be wrong?

Note: I tried the same process without the content provider, a helper inside my activity, and everything worked fine. Yet it doesn't when I do it inside the content provider...?

What could be wrong???

Comment: Examine LogCat and look at the Java stack trace associated with your "force close".

Comment: SQL_CREATE_MAIN =
       "CREATE TABLE Users (" +
       "_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
       "firstName TEXT," +
       "lastName TEXT," +
       "phoneNumber TEXT," +
       "email TEXT," +
       "username TEXT," +
       "password TEXT," +
       "gender TEXT," +
       "country TEXT);";

Answer (score 0):

you do not instantiate the database inside the Uri insert method.
The insert should look like this:

```
 @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        String tabela = "";
        Uri contentu;
        long rowID;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode2:
                tabela = TABLE_CLIENTI;
                contentu = CONTENT_URI_CLIENTI;
                break;
            case uriCode4:
                tabela = TABLE_UZERI;
                contentu = CONTENT_URI_UZERI;
                break;
            default:
                tabela = "";
                contentu = uri;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }

        rowID = db.insert(tabela, "", values);
        if (rowID > 0) {
            Log.e(TAGU,"Notify change...");
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(contentu, rowID);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to add a record into " + uri);
    }
```

where db is declared right after the contentProvider class declaration, like :

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```